# Clear text before edit in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, automated-tests

I want to clear a field text before tap a text inside. I'm trying to do an Android Test using Kotlin.

The code:

```
suspend fun navegarMenu(){
        clickSafe(R.id.nav_menu)
        waitElementAndClick(R.id.tvProfile)
        delay(4000)

// I WANT TO CLEAR THE TEXT INSIDE "et.NickName" FIELD BEFORE EDIT THE TEXT
        fillEditText(R.id.etNickName, "digdindigdin")

        delay(2000)
        clickSafe(R.id.btnAlterNickName)
        delay(10000)
    }
```

Im this case, I need to clear the field before put "digdindigdin" inside the field. I'm using Espresso JUnit on Android Studio.

Comment: which framework are you using? UiAutomator ?

Comment: Espresso JUnit on Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onView(withIdR.id.etNickName()).perform(clearText());
```